# Which components should be checked on a faulty tv power supply?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, pcb, board, tv

So, I'm new to working with electronics and I didn't study electrical engineering or anything related.
I've collected some dead tvs and monitors over time hoping that I'm gonna fix them.

I managed to fix a dead monitor by replacing some capacitors on the power board. Now I'm stuck with a dead tv. I don't have the 5V stand by to the main board and by looking at the power board's schematics I should have some 12V lanes as well to the main board which I don't have either. I checked all the electrolytic capacitors and they're all fine.

Now, the question is.. how do I proceed with the troubleshooting? Which components should I check or what should I look for now?

I can provide more details if needed.

Here's the board schematics.. I only have it as a pdf:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16dITYFEr1YRkQZ55OlUVdLGzwtFrczkv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please post the schematic diagram ... please be very careful when working on the power supply ... depending on the design, it may have hazardous voltage on the power supply output .... for example +5 V supply might be between 200 V and 205 V,  so touching either output pin may give you an unpleasant surprise

Comment: It is formal and long established site policy that repair questions are allowed *only* when the asker demonstrates a sufficiently detailed knowledge of the circuit being repaired to frame the same sort of *specific* question that would be asked about an original design.  Asking for general diagnostic strategy does not meet that requirement: try a repair forum or traditional discussion forum, *especially* if you are seeking domain knowledge of the type of product being repaired.

Comment: @Emil-Sorin Please attach the schematics as an image to the post, most users won't open an unknown file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have the 5V stand by to the main board and by looking at the
> power board's schematics I should have some 12V lanes as well to the
> main board which I don't have either.

Assuming you have ~400 V on the main power supply filter caps (C116-C121)...

This suggests the standby power supply isn't working. The controller is IC303, an [ICE3BR1765J](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ICE3BR1765J-DS-v02_03-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30431a5c32f2011a7a6a5b73688b), which has an integrated high voltage MOSFET and a 'startup cell' which takes voltage off the FET's Drain and drops it down to the lower voltage which is required to get it running. Once it has started up it powers itself via the 'AUX_12V' winding on the transformer.

[image]

First check the value of current sense resistors R301-R304, which should have a combined resistance of 0.5 Ω. If these resistors are open circuit then the IC is fried, and both it and the resistors need to be replaced. If the resistors are OK then measure voltage between pin 5 (MOSFET Drain) and pin 8 (HV ground). Note that both these points are at a high AC voltage, so be careful! If you see ~400 V then the IC is probably faulty. If you don't see high voltage on pin 5 then power is not getting to the IC for some reason, perhaps a 'dry' (cracked) solder joint or broken track on the PCB.

Other causes are possible too, but these are the most likely ones. The controller IC has high voltage stress on it and is susceptible to mains spikes. Sometimes when they blow up they take out other components around them, so you should also check the optocoupler (IC301) etc. before replacing the IC.